# Best way to work with an abstract class member in an abstract base class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm not happy with the question title, but I couldn't describe it well. I'm putting implementation in the class declarations for sake of brevity.

I have a class like this:

```
class VisibleObject {
  public:
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& rw) {
        rw.draw(*shape.get());
    }
    virtual void setSize(sf::Vector2f) = 0;

  protected:
    std::shared_ptr<sf::Shape> shape;
}
```

`sf::Shape` is an abstract class. Then I have a derived class like so:

```
class Brick : VisibleObject {
    Brick() {
        shape.reset(new sf::RectangleShape());
    }
    void setSize(sf::Vector2f newSize) {
        std::dynamic_pointer_cast<sf::RectangleShape>(shapes).get()->setSize(newSize);
    }
}
```

`sf::RectangleShape()` is a concrete class that inherits from `sf::Shape` and `setSize()` is defined for it, not `sf::Shape`, which is why I need to cast.

Of course, I need to do some error handling, in the case that the dynamic cast fails and returns an empty shared_ptr.

I'm doing this because I wanted to be able to define the `draw` method just once, since in this simple game, every object will draw their member this way. Originally I left the shape out of the base class, and e.g. Brick would just have its own private `sf::RectangleShape` that could get instantiated on the stack; which was clean, but then the draw method had to be re-written for each object type.

This works, but is uglier to work with and introduces heap allocation. I also have `shared_ptr` overhead (I would have used `unique_ptr`, but I needed dynamic casting).

Is this the most appropriate way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of mandating storage in `std::shared_ptr<sf::Shape>`, why not simply introduce a means of retrieving an `sf::Shape&` from the concrete class?

```
class VisibleObject {
    virtual sf::Shape& getShape() = 0;
public:
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& rw) {
        rw.draw(getShape());
    }
    virtual void setSize(sf::Vector2f) = 0;
};

class Brick : VisibleObject {
    sf::RectangleShape shape;
    sf::Shape& getShape() override { return shape; }
public:
    void setSize(sf::Vector2f newSize) override {
        shape.setSize(newSize);
    }
};
```

It seems ridiculous to store via a pointer to base, introducing indirections and downcasts and reference count overhead, when you could just store a plain old member. In fact, if I'm understanding the problem correctly, you could probably use a template to generate concrete classes and avoid a lot of boilerplate:

```
class VisibleObject {
public:
    virtual ~VisibleObject() {}
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderWindow&) = 0;
    virtual void setSize(sf::Vector2f) = 0;
};

template <typename Shape>
class VisibleConcreteObject : public VisibleObject {
    Shape shape;
public:
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& rw) override /* final? */ {
        rw.draw(shape);
    }
    void setSize(sf::Vector2f newSize) override /* final? */ {
        shape.setSize(newSize);
    }
};

typedef VisibleConcreteObject<sf::RectangleShape> Brick;
```

Comment: Heh, I'm new to this! That's an attractive solution, actually. I avoid the mess of a member Shape, and at the same time avoid repetition. Thanks.

Comment: @esel There's another alternative, mixing my answer and Kerrek's.

Answer (score 3):

It might be preferable to keep the interface an interface, and not start mandating implementation details. So just have an empty base class like so:

```
class VisibleObject
{
public:
    ~VisibleObject() {}

    virtual void draw(sf::RenderWindow & window) = 0;

    virtual void setSize(sf::Vector2f const & size) = 0;
};
```

You can stick the shape storage into the concrete class that implements this interface.

Moreover, `Shape` should provide a virtual resize method:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual ~Shape() {}

    virtual void resize(sf::Vector2f const & size) = 0;
};
```

Now you can make, say, a `VisibleShapeObject` as an intermediate base class:

```
class VisibleShapeObject : public VisibleObject
{
public:
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderWindow & window) override final
    {
        window.draw(*shape_);
    }

    virtual void setSize(sf::Vector2f const & size) override final
    {
        shape_->resize(size);
    }
protected:
    std::shared_ptr<Shape> shape_;    // or unique_ptr<Shape>
};
```

Comment: Regarding that first bit, I did mention (poorly) that I started off with that approach; I was simply trying to avoid the code re-use of re-writing common methods for each derived class (and also looking to learn), but it looks like I should stick to it.

Comment: As for the second part, I don't understand what `resize` provides. It doesn't look like you're implementing it anywhere, and it seems redundant since `Shape` would already provide a way to set its size.

Comment: By declaring a virtual `resize()` member in `Shape`, you eliminate the need to do any type-casting in `setSize()`, just call `resize()` like any other virtual method and let polymorphism do the work for you. By making `resize()` abstract, that is just an implementation detail that forces any `Shape` descendant to implement `resize()`. You could just as easily leave `resize()` non-abstract with a blank implementation in `Shape` itself, then descendants can override it only if they really need to. `setSize()` would not care either way.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shared everything you are trying to do, but this it one way:

```
template<ShapeT>
class VisibleObject {
public:
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& rw) {
          rw.draw(*shape.get());
    }
    virtual void setSize(sf::Vector2f) = 0;

protected:
    std::shared_ptr<ShapeT> shape;
    void reset(ShapeT* shape) {
        this->shape = shape;
    }
}

class Brick : VisibleObject<sf::RectangleShape> {
    Brick() {
        shape.reset(new sf::RectangleShape());
    }
    void setSize(sf::Vector2f newSize) {
       shape->setSize(newSize);
    }
}
```

There may be reasons why this doesn't work for you, but without more insight, I couldn't guess at what.

Comment: This is solid, though you're right, I haven't given enough insight. And I think this breaks down once I try to have different types with different behavior. For sake of knowledge, would I be able to create a map containing pointers to `VisibleObject`s, without a type? Like `map<string, VisibleObject>`?

Comment: I'm unable to edit my comment above. I left out the pointer asterisk in the map by mistake. `map<string, VisibleObject*>` (of course, I would use a smart pointer in practice)

Comment: @esel, unfortuantely no. That is indeed the drawback of this approach. You will need Kerrek's solution.